# Select from a dropdown in Android using Selenium and Appium

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, appium, android-uiautomator

I have been having issues to select from a gender dropdown on Android using Selenium and Appium, after several trials, I created this screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I select a gender type from the dropdown?

Comment: Please share your current attempts in code. For example, have you tried just using findElementById("com.appzonegroup.deja...") yet?

Comment: This is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853705/select-year-on-datepicker-using-selenium-appium-and-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

With javascript and wd as my driver provider, I use something like this:

```
let cmbBoxId = driver.waitForElementById("gender", '', timeOut, pollFreq); 
// note: Without the com.appzonegroup.dejavuandroid.zoneRevamp:id/

// Clicking the dropDown to open the listView
cmbBoxId.click();

let optionPath = "//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='" +
        "com.appzonegroup.dejavuandroid.zoneRevamp:id/spinner_item";

// You can choose to look for the option by index or text

// By Index of the desired option
// optionPath += " and @index='" + "1" + "'";

// **OR**

// By Text of the desired option
// optionPath += " and @text='" + "Female" + "'";

optionPath += "]";

//Clicking the desired option
driver.waitForElementByXPath(optionPath, '', timeOut, pollFreq).click();
```

Good luck!